# How to get the garage to work. (parking functions)

Tags: combinatorics, induction

At McGeorge's garage every driver has a favourite parking spot. Parking spots are arranged in a line and are numbered 1 through n. A driver always goes to his favourite spot, if it's free he takes it. If it's not he goes to the lowest unoccupied spot after his favourite spot. So if his favourite spot is f he tries at $f+1,f+2...$ until he finds an empty one. If he can't find an empty spot he leaves.

let $(a_1,a_2...a_n)$ be the favourite spots of drivers $(a_1,a_2...a_n)$
if driver $a_1$ parks first, then $a_2$... how many lists $(a_1,a_2....a_n)$ are there such that everyone manages to park?

Comment: Ive noticed that the order of the elements matters not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are $(n+1)^{n-1}$ such lists. They are called *parking functions*, and there is quite a literature on them. The first few pages of [this PDF](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/transparencies/parking3.pdf) give the most accessible proof that I’ve seen of the result that there are $(n+1)^{n-1}$ of them; it’s due to H.O. Pollak. It’s written rather concisely, but everything is there.

Comment: nice, I had no idea they were called like that

Comment: @Omnitic: One of my students did a survey paper on them a few years ago; they’re quite interesting.